# Storing templated class into vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, boost, unions

I'm basically trying to store templated class in a single std::vector. The current solution I'm using is a struct containing an anonymous union of the types:

```
struct SurfaceUnion
{
    enum { INT, FLOAT }Tag;
    union
    {
        GLSurface<int>*   iGLSurface;
        GLSurface<float>* fGLSurface;
    };
};

std::vector<SurfaceUnion*> vglSurfaces;
```

The problem with this is the fact that in order to parse which GLSurface I need, I have to do something like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vglSurfaces.size(); ++i)
    {
        switch (vglSurfaces[i]->Tag)
        {
        case SurfaceUnion::INT:
        {
            if (vglSurfaces[i]->iGLSurface->bIsActive && a_Camera.GetWorldSpace() == vglSurfaces[i]->iGLSurface->uiWorldSpace)
            {
                DrawSurface(*vglSurfaces[i]->iGLSurface, a_Camera);
            }
            break;
        }
        case SurfaceUnion::FLOAT:
        {
            if (vglSurfaces[i]->fGLSurface->bIsActive && a_Camera.GetWorldSpace() == vglSurfaces[i]->fGLSurface->uiWorldSpace)
            {
                DrawSurface(*vglSurfaces[i]->fGLSurface, a_Camera);
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```

Then I can finally interact with the GLSurface directly and in a way that doesn't use copy paste code

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void DrawSurface(const GLSurface<T>& ac_glSurface, const Camera<U>& a_Camera)
{
    glPushMatrix(); // Save the current matrix.

    glTranslatef(                                                                   // Move the image back to its original position
        ac_glSurface.Pos.X + (ac_glSurface.Center.X - ac_glSurface.OffsetD.W / 2),
        ac_glSurface.Pos.Y + (ac_glSurface.Center.Y - ac_glSurface.OffsetD.H / 2),
        0.0f); 
    glScalef(ac_glSurface.Scale.W, ac_glSurface.Scale.H, 0.0f);                     // Scale the image
    glRotatef(ac_glSurface.Rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                             // Rotate the image
    glTranslatef(                                                                   // Move the image to (0,0) on the screen
        -ac_glSurface.Pos.X - (ac_glSurface.Center.X - ac_glSurface.OffsetD.W / 2),
        -ac_glSurface.Pos.Y - (ac_glSurface.Center.Y - ac_glSurface.OffsetD.H / 2), 0.0f);

    DrawSurface(ac_glSurface);

    glPopMatrix(); // Reset the current matrix to the one that was saved.
}
template <typename T>
void DrawSurface(const GLSurface<T>& ac_glSurface)
{
    // Drawing the surface using glDrawArrays is here
}
```

I also have one for Cameras as well! This is far too much parsing every time I need to do something to a Camera or GLSurface. Both of these implementations combined completely removes the true genericism from the code that I was attempting to create in the first place. Now you can only have an int and a float type. To add anything else I would have to rewrite large portions of code to now parse an extra type. Not to mention this is intended to be part of a .lib, so if one is nessessary in the future it cannot be added without recompiling the .lib first. In addition, a call such as:

```
template <typename T>
void DeleteSurface(GLSurface<T>* a_pglSurface)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vglSurfaces.size(); ++i)
    {
        switch (vglSurfaces[i]->Tag)
        {
        case SurfaceUnion::INT:
        {
            if (vglSurfaces[i]->iGLSurface == a_pglSurface)
            {
                auto DeleteSurface = vglSurfaces[i]->iGLSurface;
                vglSurfaces.erase(vglSurfaces.begin() + i);
                glDeleteTextures(1, &DeleteSurface->Surface);
                delete DeleteSurface;
            }

            break;
        }
        case SurfaceUnion::FLOAT: 
        {
            // Will throw an error if uncommented
            /*if (vglSurfaces[i]->fGLSurface == a_pglSurface)
            {
                auto DeleteSurface = vglSurfaces[i]->fGLSurface;
                vglSurfaces.erase(vglSurfaces.begin() + i);
                glDeleteTextures(1, &DeleteSurface->Surface);
            }

            break;*/
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't possible because of the way templated functions work. I would need to make this 2 functions as I have done in the past and have one call the other after parsing the proper type.

So, is there a better way to use the current implementation? As in can I parse through an unknown amount of types that is connected to the 'tag' enumeration? Or is there another implementation entirely?

I know about the 'boost' library, but this is far from light weight as an addition and it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for in the first place. I need to modify the values of the GLSurface directly and cannot really just call visitor function after visitor function for it. I'd have 20 visitor functions, and the reason I'm unsatisfied with my current implementation is its loss of genericism and redundant function calls after a parse. I'd essentially have the same thing as I have now, but with a huge dependency include folder

I'm also aware of polymorphism, however I don't think having a base class will help as I need to look at differently typed member variables which a base class will not allow me to do.

Any help is very much appreciated, as I've been stuck with this terrible code I've written for quite some time.

Comment: I didn't read all the post, but what's wrong with `std::vector<yourclass<T>>`?

Comment: Same here. Read through and couldn't figure out what's the point of having two different instantiations.

Comment: This is all inside of a namespace. Even if it wasn't, the point is to hold both GLSurface<int> and GLSurface<float> in the same vector...You can't just say std::vector<'MyClass'<T>> unless T has been defined to be a type as far as I'm aware, and that type is absolute, meaning it couldn't change from int to float. That is unless I don't understand templating at all.

Comment: _"[...] completely removes the true genericism from the code that I was attempting to create in the first place"_ - Oh I think all C++ programmers who first drank the "generic code" kool-aid have been at this painful point where they realize that there are boundaries that templates won't easily cross (C APIs? Isolated TUs?). In time you'll know how to predict these boundaries and to design for them from the start. Until then, it will hurt. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the different types.

You *can* store dynamic instances by polymorphic reference (std::reference_wrapper) or (smart) pointer, iff your classes share a common base.

Otherwise you should use static polymorphism. You could look at `boost::variant<GLSurface<float>, GLSurface<int>>` for example.

To operate on these uniformly, you will end up doing something that's a hybrid between static and runtime polymorphism: type erase.

With the type erasure technique you basically bring (unrelated) types under a shared *ad-hoc interface*.

Comment: I looked up 'type erasure'. The example I found was this one: 

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/

The example does not have any member variables in the structs. Am I allowed member variables? And would I access them through a 'getter' function? Without being able to retrieve the values directly somehow, type erasure isn't a viable solution for me. I am interested in the concept though, and would like to know if it works differently than I saw in the example.

Comment: Looks like a fair example. `std::function<>` also does it. Boost Type Erase is a whole library around it.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using boost if possible if for no other reason than installing it on every machine I use at home/school would be too much hassle. std::function<> looks over my head, but I can ask my professor about it possibly. Would you be able to look at my comment again? I accidentally hit return when typing the link, and you are incredibly quick to answer! Thank you

Comment: I think it works differently from what you _understand_ not so much from what you see. Really, I'd urge you to reconsider your design. You give me all the signals that you'd actually be better off with either separate vectors _or_ dynamic polymorphism (e.g. inheritance and virtual functions). Then use e.g. `std::vector<some_ptr<Base>>`. Good luck

Comment: Possibly, but every single member variable is templated to a single type and GLSurface is a struct with no member functions. My design is certainly not good, so other options are welcome. I'll look up what you've suggested and ask my professor about it. I'm sure I can figure something out with what you've said. Thank you.